# PasteButton does not work on wolfram player on ios

Tags: cdf-format

For Example

```
DynamicModule[{x}, x = 0; Panel[Row[{InputField[Dynamic[x]], PasteButton[2], Dynamic[x]}]]]
```

on wolfram player under macos, when I select the inputfield and click the button, it will paste 2 in inputfield
[image]

but it doesn't work on ios
[image]

Comment: I think you may want to ask Wolfram Support about this - I'm not sure how much we can help you on it here. It sounds like a bug in the iOS player app.

Comment: Nothing really works in the iOS app and no one is working on improving it sadly